# Find the 5 oldest (earliest) requests which are not yet accepted

Tags: mysql, database

I am new to MySQL. Can anyone please tell the answer for this question?

Table **Requests**, which has following schema:

Field              |  Type

---

requestNumber(PK)  |  int

requestDate        |  date

requiredDate       |  date

acceptedDate       |  date

status             |  char(16)

comments           |  char(201)

requesterNumber    |  int

Note: if accepted status = "Accepted"

Answer (score 1):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select *
from `Requests`
where `status` <> 'Accepted'
order by `requestDate` asc
limit 5
```